# Is there a docker registry cluster solution for private purpose?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I am looking for an open source solution to sync several docker registries. Could anybody give me some hints about this?

Comment: Why don't you use an amazon S3 or Openstack Swift backend? Multiple registry instances would then share the same set of images.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do have interest to implement a docker registry cluster, but don't know how to do that. Do you have any reference?

Comment: https://github.com/docker/docker-registry

Comment: I know the post is older but what about [flocker](https://github.com/clusterhq/flocker) I never used it but it seem to solve some data problems. Anyway if you like to run a docker registry you need to have a shared storage for all registries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to set up a docker registry is using the [official docker registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/). This allows you to easily run a registry server with a configurable storage backend. As others have mentioned you can use S3 or Google Cloud storage. (I have personally used Google Cloud storage and have not run into any problems).

I would also check out this digital ocean post about setting up a docker registry: [How to setup a docker registry](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-private-docker-registry-on-ubuntu-14-04).

Since you are interested in clustering, all you would need to do at this point is setup multiple registry servers with the same bucket as a storage backend. Then put a load balancer such as [haproxy](http://www.haproxy.org/) or [nginx](http://nginx.org/) in front of them. This will give you the fault tolerance and load balancing that you are looking for.

Comment: I'm using the same setup, but I use amazon's ELB, now when I try to push images, I got `blob upload unknown`. Is there a cluster setup for the registry?

Comment: @Casper that seems like it might be a separate issue, if you open up a new question with some more details about the problem you are running into I could take a look.

Comment: I have new issue now, please help take a look https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/1576

Comment: Doesn't this create a single point of failure in the bucket? This mostly defeats the purpose of having a registry cluster, doesn't it?

Comment: This answer seems to be obsolete for docker swarm mode.  Not that this is solved by docker swarm mode, but the ingress network or some overlay network system should be usable for load balancing.