# How can i mirror a private docker registry to other docker registry server?

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-registry

i want to clone a private docker registry on other machine. Is it possible to copy or mirror all images available on one registry server to other registry server.

Is it possible to do a scp of all repositories available on one registry server to my other registry server.

Comment: You could look at different storage options for the registry, and have two different registries pointing to the same storage:
https://docs.docker.com/registry/configuration/#storage
And have a look at this as well, it suggests multiple registries backed by the same s3 bucket as storage : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31030197/249687